# Validate url params not in model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to validate url params that are not in the model.

Specifically I have a route like below:

```
get 'delivery_windows/:date',
        to: 'delivery_windows#index',
        :constraints => { :date => /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ },
        as: :delivery_windows
```

I want to make sure that :date is a valid date and regex is not a solution. the date cant be in the past and not more than 3 months into the future.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't it easier to just post the date as a GET var? like delivery_windows?date=xxxx-xx-xx, you can easily check this with params[:date].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to theunraveler and sadaf2605 for their responses.

I ended up doing to combination of their suggestions by using the before_action and raising a routing error in there.

in my controller I added:

```
class AngularApi::V1::DeliveryWindowsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :validate_date_param, only: :index

  def index
    ...
  end

  private

  def validate_date_param
    begin
      Date.parse(params[:date])
    rescue ArgumentError
      render json: [{
        param: :date,
        message: "Incorrect Date Format: Date format should be yyyy-mm-dd."
      }].to_json, status: :unprocessable_entity
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not sure that I would handle this in the routing layer myself, you should be able to use [Advanced Routing Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) for this.

The idea is that `constraints` can accept an object that responds to `matches?`. If `matches?` returns true, then the constraint passes, otherwise, the constraint fails. A simple implementation of this would be the following:

In your `config/routes.rb`, including something like this:

```
require 'routing/date_param_constraint'

get 'delivery_windows/:date',
    to: 'delivery_windows#index',
    constraints: DateParamConstraint,
    as: :delivery_windows
```

Then, somewhere in your application (perhaps in `lib/routing/date_param_constraint.rb`), define a class like the following:

```
module DateParamConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    # Check `request.parameters[:date]` to make sure
    # it is valid here, return true or false.
  end
end
```

Comment: where would you say is the correct place to handle this error and how?

Comment: I would probably handle it in the controller with a `before_action`, mostly because as a user, I would expect to get a more helpful message when I specify an invalid parameter. For example, if the date I specified was out of range, I would expect that I would be told that, rather than getting a sort of generic 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can filter your date at controller, and raise `404 not found` when you get date that does not fulfil your requirement.

```
def show
    date=params[:date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d').to_date
    if date > 0.day.ago or date > 3.month.from_now
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
end
```